# Next.js Cloudinary images not displaying with loader

Tags: next.js, cloudinary, nextjs-image

I am trying to use `next/image` component with cloudinary.com and cloudinary loader. But my image doesn't display with loader, it only shows without loader.

### WITHOUT LOADER

`next.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    images: {   
        domains: ['res.cloudinary.com'],
    },
}
```

My image component:

```
<Image src="https://res.cloudinary.com/eminvarol/image/upload/v1625915405/index-backround_rubhkh.jpg" width={500} height={500}/>
```

and this is working in here

[image]

### WITH LOADER

`next.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    images: {   
        domains: ['res.cloudinary.com'],
        loader: 'cloudinary'
    },
}
```

My image component is same:

```
<Image src="https://res.cloudinary.com/eminvarol/image/upload/v1625915405/index-backround_rubhkh.jpg" width={500} height={500}/>
```

With loader, my page looks like this

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is slightly different when using a valid third-party loader. You need to define a `loader` and a `path`.

```js
module.exports = {
    images: {
        loader: 'cloudinary',
        path: '<cloudinary-path-here>'
    }
}
```

Check out the [Image Optimization docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader) for more details.

Comment: Thank you bro I add the path https://res.cloudinary.com/eminvarol/'   and change my image src from https://res.cloudinary.com/eminvarol/......." to image_name.jpg